# Galois extension over power series fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field, and $L$ be an algebraic extension of $K$.
I think it is known that if $T$ is a finite extension of $K((X))$, then $T$ is complete with respect to the $X$-adic valuation, hence if $T$ is included in $L((X))$, $T= N((X))$ for some finite extension $N$ of $K$ (true ?).

1) Is $L((X))$ an algebraic extension of $K((X))$ ?

2) assuming that 1) is true, am I right to say that if $L/K$ is Galois, then Gal($L/K$) is isomorphic to Gal($L((X))/K((X))$) ?

thx.

Comment: 1) There are counterexamples for $K=\mathbb Q$ and $L$ the algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: can you be more specific (eventually link, sources) ?

Comment: Eventually a hint: let $a_n$ be a root of $X^{p_n}-2$ (here $p_n$ stands for the $n$th prime number) and consider the series $\sum a_nX^n$ which is not algebraic over $\mathbb Q((X))$.

Comment: For your unnumbered first point, this is also false. For example, let $T = K((\sqrt{X}))$; then $T$ is not of the form $N((X))$.

Comment: Part 1 does work if you assume that $L/K$ is a finite extension :-)

Comment: @circonflexe Thx for your remark: I forgot to add a condition in the question. This has been fixed.

Comment: That $L((X))$, which is $X$-adically complete, is not necessarily algebraic over $K((X))$ when $L/K$ is algebraic is similar to the proof that the algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$ is not complete:an infinite series $\sum a_np^n$ where $a_n$ is a root of unity of order $p^n-1$ lies in the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$ but is not in the algebraic closure itself.